# CSRF protection question

Tags: php, security, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm currently in the process of implementing CSRF protection into my framework (PHP).

However I am wondering:

Wouldn't it be possible for an attacker to load my page in a (hidden) iframe (obtaining the token) and change some data using JavaScript?

And after that submitting the form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless the attacker's page has the same domain, protocol and port as yours (if it is, you probably have more serious problems), they won't be able to read the `iframe`'s HTML because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Ok kewl. I thought the Same Origin Policy only meant we couldn't do requests.

Comment: @PeeHaa: It depends on the context. With an `iframe`, it means unless the domain, port and protocol match, you can not access the `iframe`'s DOM.